# The option in the panel shows the length of the Grease Pencil line when drawing

Tags: python, grease-pencil, operator

This code shows the parameter change on Panel, BUT it is done after releasing the mouse button.

If I replace return {'PASS_THROUGH'} with return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}, the parameter is updated correctly, but the cursor is blocked for drawing.

Is there any way to do it at the same time, when the parameter changes while drawing?

Thank you!

[image]

'''

```
    import bpy
    from bpy.props import IntProperty, FloatProperty

    class SimplePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
        bl_label = "Panel"
        bl_idname = "VIEW3D_PT_simple_value"
        bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
        bl_region_type = 'UI'
        bl_category = 'Custom'

        def draw(self, context):
            layout = self.layout
            layout.prop(context.scene, "delta_value")

    class ModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
        bl_idname = "object.modal_operator"
        bl_label = "Simple Modal Operator"

        first_mouse_x: IntProperty()
        first_value: FloatProperty()

        def __init__(self):
            print("Start")

        def __del__(self):
            print("End")

        def execute(self, context):       # ??? 
    
            return {'FINISHED'}           # ???

        def modal(self, context, event):
            if event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':
                if event.value == 'PRESS':
                    self.first_mouse_x = event.mouse_x
                    self.left_mouse_pressed = True            
                elif event.value == 'RELEASE':
                    self.left_mouse_pressed = False
            

            if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':
                self.execute(context) # ???
                delta = event.mouse_x - self.first_mouse_x
                self.first_mouse_x = event.mouse_x
                context.scene.delta_value += abs(delta) * 0.01
                for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
                    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                        area.tag_redraw()
        
        
        
            elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
                print("Exiting modal operator")
                return {'CANCELLED'} 

    

            return {'PASS_THROUGH'}#return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

        def invoke(self, context, event):
            if context.object:
                self.delta_value = context.scene.delta_value
                self.first_mouse_x = event.mouse_x
                context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
                return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
            else:
                self.report({'WARNING'}, "No active object, could not finish")
                return {'CANCELLED'}

        def menu_func(self, context):
            self.layout.operator(ModalOperator.bl_idname, text=ModalOperator.bl_label)

    def register():
        bpy.utils.register_class(ModalOperator)
        bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)
        bpy.utils.register_class(SimplePanel)
        bpy.types.Scene.delta_value = FloatProperty(name="Delta Value", default=0.0, description="A floating point value to be adjusted")

    def unregister():
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalOperator)
        bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_func)
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimplePanel)
        del bpy.types.Scene.delta_value

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        register()

    # test call
        bpy.ops.object.modal_operator('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

'''